# WPF: How to translateTransform a rectangle?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to move a rectangle drawn in Canvas by mouse  (drag and drop).

When I click on the Rectangle and move the mouse (keep clicking) to a new position it's OK:

[image]

But when I click on it again and move the mouse just a bit the Rectangle move to old position:

[image]

I don't know why it is. Can anybody give me some explaination?

Here is my code (all parameters have been assigned and initialized).
Thanks in advance!

```
private void MyCanvas_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        { 
            if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.OriginalSource is Shape)
            {
                p2 = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
                TranslateTransform tf = new TranslateTransform(p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y);
                _MyTestRect.RenderTransform = tf;
            }

        }
private void MyCanvas_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.OriginalSource is Shape)
            {
                p1 = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
            }

        }
```

Comment: If you are trying to implement a drag&drop effect, use the [appropriate WPF elements and code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742859(v=vs.100).aspx) , don't try to implement it from scratch. WPF already supports drag&drop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mvvm Behavior Approach add the refference to:
    System.Windows.Interactivity.

1. In XAML:

   ```
   <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="#00FFFFFF">
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <!--soSandBox is the reffrence to the behavior-->
       <soSandBox:MoveElementsInCanvasBehavior/>
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <Rectangle x:Name="_MyTestRect1" Fill="Tomato" Width="50" Height="50"/>
   <Rectangle x:Name="_MyTestRect2" Fill="Tomato" Width="50" Height="50"/>
   <Rectangle x:Name="_MyTestRect3" Fill="Tomato" Width="50" Height="50"/></Canvas>
   ```
2. Behavior code:

   ```
   protected override void OnAttached()
   {
       base.OnAttached();
       AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += AssociatedObjectOnMouseLeftButtonDown;
       AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += AssociatedObjectOnMouseLeftButtonUp;
       AssociatedObject.MouseMove += AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove;
   }

   private void AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (_shape != null && _shape.IsMouseCaptured)
       {
           _p2 = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
           _shape.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, _p2.Y - _originalOffsetFromTop);
           _shape.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, _p2.X - _originalOffsetFromLeft);
       }
   }

   private void AssociatedObjectOnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       if (_shape == null) return;
       _shape.ReleaseMouseCapture();
       _shape = null;
   }

   private double GetDist(double originalValue, double newValue)
   {
       if (double.IsNaN(originalValue) || double.IsInfinity(originalValue))
           return Math.Abs(newValue - 0);
       return Math.Abs(newValue - originalValue);
   }

   private void AssociatedObjectOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       _shape = e.OriginalSource as Shape;
       if (_shape != null)
       {
           _p1 = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
           _shape.CaptureMouse();
           _originalOffsetFromTop = GetDist((double)_shape.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty), _p1.Y);
           _originalOffsetFromLeft = GetDist((double)_shape.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty), _p1.X);
       }
   }

   protected override void OnDetaching()
   {
       base.OnDetaching();
       AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown -= AssociatedObjectOnMouseLeftButtonDown;
       AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp -= AssociatedObjectOnMouseLeftButtonUp;
       AssociatedObject.MouseMove -= AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove;
   }
   ```

   3. Summary:
      This way you can put inside the canvas as much elements as you wish, and when you click the element (and when this element is a shape) you will be able to move it.

[image]

4. Translate Transform XAML:

   ```
   <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="#00FFFFFF">
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <!--convert event to command mechanism-->
       <soSandBox:CanvasMouseEventObservingBehavior 
           OnMouseMoveAction="{Binding OnMouseMoveAction, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           OnMouseRightButtonDownAction="{Binding OnMouseRightButtonDownAction, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           OnMouseRightButtonUpAction="{Binding OnMouseRightButtonUpAction, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <Rectangle x:Name="_MyTestRect1" Fill="Tomato" Width="50" Height="50">
       <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
           <TransformGroup>
               <TranslateTransform X="{Binding TranslateTransformX, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                   Y="{Binding TranslateTransformY, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></TranslateTransform>
           </TransformGroup>
       </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
   </Rectangle></Canvas>
   ```
5. Translate Transform view model (translation related code):

   ```
       private void RightMouseUp(Point obj)
   {
       _originalPoint = obj;
       _currentOffsetByX = GetDist(_currentOffsetByX, obj.X);
       _currentOffsetByY = GetDist(_currentOffsetByY, obj.Y);

   }

   private void RightMouseDown(Point obj)
   {
       _originalPoint = obj;
       _currentOffsetByX = GetDist(_currentOffsetByX, obj.X);
       _currentOffsetByY = GetDist(_currentOffsetByY, obj.Y);
   }

   private void MouseMoved(Point obj)
   {
       TranslateTransformX = obj.X - _currentOffsetByX;
       TranslateTransformY = obj.Y - _currentOffsetByY;
   }

   private double GetDist(double originalValue, double newValue)
   {
       if (double.IsNaN(originalValue) || double.IsInfinity(originalValue))
           return Math.Abs(newValue - 0);
       return Math.Abs(newValue - originalValue);
   }

   public double TranslateTransformY
   {
       get { return _translateTransformY; }
       set
       {
           _translateTransformY = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   public double TranslateTransformX
   {
       get { return _translateTransformX; }
       set
       {
           _translateTransformX = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }
   ```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should not create the transform every time otherwise you reset the translation.

Create a TranslateTransform if none exist.

Then cumulate the translations inside.

Regards

Comment: @Duy where is the edit? The question still shows creating a new transform each time. In any case, the transform element should be put in XAML and the angle should be bound to a viewmodel property. Instead of trying to change the transform at each mouse event, simply change that value and let databinding notify the transformation element

Answer (score 0):

Try just using the [Canvas.SetTop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Canvas.SetLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
myRectangle += myRectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown;

void myRectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    myRectangle.MouseMove += origin_MouseMove;
}

void myRectangle_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = new Point()
    {   
        // Just round the coordinates
        X = Math.Round(e.GetPosition(canvas).X, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),  
        Y = Math.Round(e.GetPosition(canvas).Y, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),
    };

    Canvas.SetTop(myRectangle, p.Y);
    Canvas.SetLeft(myRectangle, p.X);

    myRectangle.MouseLeftButtonUp += myRectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp;
}

void myRectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    myRectangle.MouseMove -= origin_MouseMove;
    myRectangle.MouseLeftButtonUp -= origin_MouseLeftButtonUp;
}
```